The app build failed to produce artifact folder: 'frontend/dist/'. Please ensure this property is configured correctly in your workflow file
I am trying to deploy a monorepo consisting of a React (Vite) frontend and a Node.js backend.
The project is seperated in folders a backend and frontend folder. When my workflow runs I get the error: "The app build failed to produce artifact folder: 'frontend/dist/'."
I've tried to manually build the frontend project to see if it actually created a dist folder in my frontend folder, and it does.
What am I doing wrong?
This is my workflow file:
name: Build and Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "18.x"

      - name: Install dependencies and build frontend
        run: |
          cd frontend
          npm install
          npm run build
      - name: Log frontend directory contents
        run: |
          echo "Logging frontend directory contents"
          ls -la ./frontend
          echo "Logging frontend/dist directory contents"
          ls -la ./frontend/dist
      - name: Install dependencies for backend
        run: |
          cd backend
          npm install
      - name: Log backend directory contents
        run: |
          echo "Logging backend directory contents"
          ls -la ./backend
      - name: Deploy to Azure Static Web Apps
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "./frontend" # The location of your application source code.
          api_location: "backend" # The location of your API source code.
          app_artifact_location: "frontend/dist/" # The location of your build output directory.
          app_build_command: "npm run build"
          api_build_command: "" # No build command for the backend


I've added this to my vite.config.js file:
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    outDir: "dist",
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1000, // Increase the chunk size limit to 1000 kB

    manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      // overwrite default .html entry
      input: "/src/main.jsx",
    },
    // other build options
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});

I've tried changing app_artifact_location to following: "dist" "./dist", "dist/ and still error

The GitHub Actions workflow is unable to find the expected build artifacts in the specified location.

The Azure Static Web Apps build configuration either uses GitHub Actions or Azure Pipelines. Each site has a YAML configuration file that controls how a site is built and deployed. This MSDOC explains the file's structure and options.

From this MSDOC , Azure Static Web Apps provide  support only for integrating APIs, whether through managed Azure Functions or by bringing your own APIs hosted in other Azure services.
Follow the below steps for  Azure Static Web configuration with git.

After creating a new Vite project using npm, add the code to fetch data/ messages  from back end in the frontend

App.vue:
The below sample code fetches a message from an API/backend and displays it in an UI.
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: ''
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api') /
      .then(response => {
        this.message = response.data.message;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was an error fetching the data!', error);
      });
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>

I Configured the backend/api using this document  .
Add Staticwebapp.config.json to the root directory of the front end.
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html"
  }
}

Git Hub Folder Strucure:


Now change the git yml according to your Folder Strucure

app_location to `./vite-project`,
api_location` to `./my-backend` ,
output_location to "dist" 

Yml:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_WITTY_POND_06001940F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
          action: "upload"
       
          app_location: "./vite-project" 
          api_location: "./my-backend" 
          output_location: "dist" 
       

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_WITTY_POND_06001940F }}
          action: "close"


Deployement status:

Azure  Static  Web App:


Huge thank you. I really appreciate it
